# Javascript kept saying undefined

Tags: javascript

So I am following a javascript course on codecademy, I decided to try things out on my own script. So the script is:

```
function family1 (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var family = new Array();

family[0] = new family1("alice", 40);
family[1] = new family1("bob", 42);
family[2] = new family1("michelle", 8);
family[3] = new family1("timmy", 8);

printFamily1 = function(person) {
        console.log(person.name + " aged " + person.age);
}

console.log(printFamily1(family[0]))
console.log(printFamily1(family[1]))
console.log(printFamily1(family[2]))
console.log(printFamily1(family[3]))
```

It works, but in the console, it printed

```
alice aged 40
undefined
bob aged 42
undefined
michelle aged 8
undefined
timmy aged 8
undefined
```

It works, but I don't want the undefined part! How do I fix these!

Comment: `printFamily1` function returns `undefined` (since it returns nothing). If you don't want it - don't output it, but simply `printFamily1(family[0])`

Comment: @zerkms YOU SAVED MY LIFE! TYSM! I'm such a dumbass.

Comment: why you didnt just return a string and print in on the console like that: printFamily = function(person) { return person.name + " aged " + person.age; } and then just saying console.log(printFamily(person[0])):

Answer (score 0):

Update your printFamily1 function to look like this:

```
printFamily1 = function(person) {
        console.log(person.name + " aged " + person.age); 
        return (person.name + " aged " + person.age);
}
```

The issue is your trying to print what `printFamily1` returns, but you don't have a return defined. So Simply add a return of what you want to be printed in your console

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Don't call `console.log` again:

   ```
   printFamily1(family[0])
   printFamily1(family[1])
   printFamily1(family[2])
   printFamily1(family[3])
   ```
2. Don't call `console.log` inside the function

   ```
   printFamily1 = function(person) {
       return person.name + " aged " + person.age;
   }
   ```